# Making a Windows 8 ListView editable?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is there a way to make a `ListView` in Windows 8 editable, using Javascript?

For example, when I put an input element inside of the template of the items?

I see the input, and its value is set, but I can't click in it.

My list looks like this:

```
 <div class="InputList">
                <div class="employeeList" id="employeeL"
                    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
                    itemDataSource: employee.groupedItemsList.dataSource, 
                    itemTemplate: select('#employeeListTemplate'),
                    selectionMode: 'single', 
                    tapBehavior: 'directSelect',
                    layout:{type:WinJS.UI.ListLayout}}">
            </div>
```

And my template:

```
        <div id="employeeListTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div class="employeeItem">
                <input data-win-bind="innerText:Name" />
                <label data-win-bind="innerText:Vorname"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `win-interactive` class to the element that you want to be interactive.